# Advanced Generic Types lenght of Array has to match amount of keys in related object

Tags: typescript, types

Is there a possibility to create type safety across rows and columns where one object defines the structure of the other one?

Initial Situation:

```
export interface TableColumn {
  name: string;
  type: "string" | "number" | "action"; // this type is an arbitrary type and is needed for default rendering so we know how to display it. 
  id: string;
}

export interface PaginatedTableProps {
  /** `rows` data must match the "schema" provided in `columns` */
  rows: any[]; // <-- Goal would be to get rid of any
  /** `columns` define the schema for the table and data provided in `rows` must match */
  columns: TableColumn[];
}
```

Now the rows need to match the structure defined in the columns seen the example below. I also try to add optional Parameter over the TableRowProps interface, those can be added to each row if needed.

```
// These props are optional but can be added to any Row in PaginatedTableProps.rows
interface TableRowProps {
  rowType?: "Basic" | "Master";
}

export interface TableColumn {
  name: string;
  type: "string" | "number" | "action"; // this type is an arbitrary type and is needed for default rendering so we know how to display it. 
  id: string;
}

export interface PaginatedTableProps {
  /** `rows` data must match the "schema" provided in `columns` */
  rows: Array<TableRowProps | Record<string, unknown>>;
  /** `columns` define the schema for the table and data provided in `rows` must match */
  columns: TableColumn[];
}

// Example use:
const props: PaginatedTableProps = {
    columns: [
        { name: "f", type: "string", id: "1" },
        { name: "count", type: "number", id: "2" },
        { name: "z", type: "string", id: "3", }
    ],
    rows: [
        {f:"foo", count: 12345, z: "bar"},
        {f:"zig", count: 6789}, // should mark an error that z is missing
        {f:"bar", count: "123", z: "far"}, // should mark an error that count is not a number
        {f:"bas", count: 123, z: "asdf", rowType:"Basic"}, // ok
        {f:"bas", count: 123, z: "asdf", rowType:"Expert"} // should be wrong as the rowType needs to match Basic or Master
    ]
}
```

EDIT: I omitted the additional CellRenderer from the first example this would be a next step to add type safety to here:

```
interface TableRowProps {
    rowType?: "Basic" | "Master";
}

export interface TableColumn {
    name: string;
    type: "string" | "number" | "action";
    id: string;
    renderFunction?: (data: any) => string; // any should match the Type selected  in Types maybe this is impossible.
}

export interface PaginatedTableProps {
    /** `rows` data must match the "schema" provided in `columns` */
    rows: Array<TableRowProps | Record<string, unknown>>;
    /** `columns` define the schema for the table and data provided in `rows` must match */
    columns: TableColumn[];
}

// Example use:
const props: PaginatedTableProps = {
    columns: [
        { name: "f", type: "string", id: "1" },
        { name: "count", type: "number", id: "2" },
        { name: "z", type: "string", id: "3", renderFunction: (s: string) => s}
    ],
    rows: [
        {f:"foo", count: 12345, z: "bar"},
        {f:"zig", count: 6789}, // should mark an error that z is missing
        {f:"bar", count: "123", z: "far"}, // should mark an error that count is not a number
        {f:"bas", count: 123, z: "asdf", rowType:"Basic"}, // ok
        {f:"bas", count: 123, z: "asdf", rowType:"Expert"} // should be wrong as the rowType needs to match Basic or Master
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your array : rows = [{"foo", 12345, "bar"},
        {"zig", 6789, "zag"}];

Comment: Your 2nd code snippet includes invalid syntax. Is `rows` supposed to be an array of arrays?

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre].  A non-exhaustive list of things to clear up: Where's `"Basic"` or `"Master"` in the code example?  Why is `12345` supposed to match `type: "string"`?  (Others have pointed out the invalid syntax) What does a `type: "action"` look like? Why the apparent dependency on `React.Element`? Could we remove the `cellRenderer` entirely from the question without changing it?

Comment: (see previous comments).  If I make a bunch of assumptions about what you're trying to do, I get [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXr09m).  Does that meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining (after you [edit] to clear up those issues); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz i changed the code example - i don't really know how to define the problems with the correct words i hope the code and comments makes it clear enough

Comment: @jcalz and yes i think your approach goes exactly into the right direction! I will try and implement that approach and would be very grateful about further explanation or moreover for links to dig deeper into it :+1

Comment:  I asked what `{type: "action"}` is supposed to look like; you left it in there but didn't show an example of it, so I have no idea what it's supposed to be.  I'll write up an answer but if the `"action"` part doesn't work then ‍♂️ I guess you'll have to fix it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work we'll need to set up a mapping between the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `type` property in `TableColumn` to the actual data type.  Luckily there's an easy way to describe a mapping between a string literal type and some arbitrary type: an [`interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces).  Let's call it `TypeMap`:

```
interface TypeMap {
    string: string;
    number: number;
    action: (x: string) => void; // who knows
}
```

(I don't know what an "`action`" is so ‍♂️).  Then you can define `TableColumn` in terms of `TypeMap`:

```
type TableColumn = { [P in keyof TypeMap]: {
    name: string;
    type: P
    id: string;
    renderFunction?: (data: TypeMap[P]) => string;
} }[keyof TypeMap]
```

Before explaining how that works, let's make sure it's something useful:

```
/* type TableColumn = {
    name: string;
    type: "string";
    id: string;
    renderFunction?: ((data: string) => string) | undefined;
} | {
    name: string;
    type: "number";
    id: string;
    renderFunction?: ((data: number) => string) | undefined;
} | {
    name: string;
    type: "action";
    id: string;
    renderFunction?: ((data: (x: string) => void) => string) | undefined;
} */
```

So `TableColumn` is a [discriminated union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) with `type` as the discriminant property, and where the parameter type of the `renderFunction` method depends on that `type`.

Okay, so how it works: `TableColumn` is created as a *distributive object type* as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  It's a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) into which we immediately [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) in order to get a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of its property values.

---

Now, there's not really a *specific* `PaginatedTableProps` type in TypeScript that meets your needs, whereby the `rows` and `columns` properties are constrained to each other in the right way.  Instead we'll need to define a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `PaginatedTableProps<T>` type, where `T` corresponds to the type of the `columns` property, and where `rows` is some type that depends on `T`.  It could look like this:

```
interface PaginatedTableProps<T extends readonly TableColumn[]> {
    columns: T;
    rows: Array<{
        [I in keyof T & `${number}` as T[I]["name"]]: TypeMap[T[I]["type"]]
    } & TableRowProps>;
}
```

The `rows` property is an `Array` type whose elements' type is the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of `TableRowProps` with a mapped type that turns the array of `TableColumn` subtypes from `T` into an object type whose keys are [remapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to the `name` property of the `TableColumn`s, and whose properties are what you get when you look the corresponding `type` property up in the `TypeMap` interface.

---

Generic types like `PaginatedTableProps<T>` are annoying to [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) directly on variable declarations because you have to specify the type argument `T` manually, and that could be quite verbose and repetitive.

Instead we can make a generic helper function `paginatedTableProps()` that *infers* the type argument `T` from its argument and returns it as-is, like this:

```
const paginatedTableProps = <const T extends readonly TableColumn[]>(
    ptp: PaginatedTableProps<T>) => ptp;
```

(Note that we use a [`const` type parameter](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#const-type-parameters) to tell the compiler to try to infer very specific types for `T`... we care about the string literal types of the `name` properties of `rows` elements, after all.)

And so instead of writing `const p: PaginatedTableProps = { ⋯ }` which you can't do because `PaginatedTableProps` is generic; and instead of writing `const p: PaginatedTableProps< ⋯ > = { ⋯ }` which is tedious and redundant; you write `const p = paginatedTableProps({ ⋯ })` and you'll see that `p` is inferred as desired.

---

Okay, let's try it out:

```
const p = paginatedTableProps({
    columns: [
        { name: "f", type: "string", id: "1" },
        { name: "count", type: "number", id: "2" },
        { name: "z", type: "string", id: "3", renderFunction: (s: string) => s }
    ],
    rows: [
        { f: "foo", count: 12345, z: "bar" }, // okay
        { f: "zig", count: 6789 }, // error,
        //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- z is missing
        { f: "bar", count: "123", z: "far" }, // error
        //          ~~~~~ <-- string isn't a number
        { f: "baz", count: 123, z: "asdf", rowType: "Basic" }, // okay
        { f: "qux", count: 123, z: "ghjk", rowType: "Expert" } // error,
        // ------------------------------> ~~~~~~~ not "Basic" or "Master"
    ]
})
```

That looks like the behavior you want.  The compiler knows that the `columns` property elements must be of type `{f: string, count: number, z: string, rowType?: "Basic" | "Master"}`, and you get errors accordingly if you mess up.  And the type of `p` is inferred as

```
/* const p: PaginatedTableProps<readonly [{
    readonly name: "f";
    readonly type: "string";
    readonly id: "1";
}, {
    readonly name: "count";
    readonly type: "number";
    readonly id: "2";
}, {
    readonly name: "z";
    readonly type: "string";
    readonly id: "3";
    readonly renderFunction: (s: string) => string;
}]> */
```

which captures the entire `rows` structure and would be quite annoying to write out... which means it's a good thing it was inferred for us!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOECydPIDeAUMmcgM5hSgDmAXJdXQNynkgCuAtgEbSMufaG3LJEYYAHsQjABQAPRlRohaASmQBeAHzIAblOAATFsgD055AHcAFlOQBrEFOsViAX2LEwWFKjheABsIAGEpIJ4QbSJkAG0ABWRQJwh0KRg0PzxMAF1GEjEQOG4IZWY1UXJfbEYE9jITctVaKrIoCBBjaAAxThAESRkAfnljODA4RgxsHMTczV0mFrYPZA84xzSMrNn8XO9icwAqZBr-QJDwyO5orSIG5GLS5tZH88YAIhU6T7bk4yvSqPDpdXr9QbSECjZByOTjSZAjTaPQ-NSaAA+yH63RgoAgpk8yCxhQ4JTKyzeYg+yE+Qn4UD+jyalOBYlB3SgfQGQ2h8nhEymTx4DMWqIqyKxOIgeJABNWxIeRXJSP+NM+EihTLELLRrRBnU53MhI35CKFiiRYoMRmM1r1mOxYNl8qJx3Mh1AkFgiAuwQgACVXAkoFJMBQleRQ9YZhAYZ8AEJwCjABCfRWfPBUaBMrzEL3QeBIZAJOC0UATAkBf0hsMUAA8qGQEAUkC6EY6cGMMiC6DQlzCESicVyelJZAQQ9uFGm-2jM+QAEEoFA4Oh6+OxPEAJLJaJbdKZJsAMmQAAMACSEenQDxn8QR1Bxbe5OJ08mfXL5Xa4fBxJ8vm+5yfgcYhrKe1YhEG1i1uGOirN4k4gFQyCYGWFaQMYkEQLBEb3PWSEoU2LZtsYHYQF2PZ9th1zDqOciPJgYCYHU6HFJh2G4Y2OjWkxmBsMQhFgKhMRoeW7FVgOuFyJuk43MhjBxI8YiEE8Kq0jAnwADRnH4Xx6tpAJfAAjOmHhacp5Cqc8FKfJO-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)

Comment: Very nice explanation! I definitely need to dig a bit deeper in the docs but it's a great start!